# r plotly scatterplot with continuous color won't show NA color when there are two values (1 value, 1 NA)

Tags: r, plotly, na

I've been trying to make a scatterplot in plotly which shows the same numeric column with some NA's, in two plot elements (color and symbol).

When there are **only two values in a group, one number and one NA**, the plot for the NA element shows some value instead of the NA color (which is gray).

I know it has to do with building the continuous palette when there are only two values, but i haven't been able to fix this.
I'm building a dynamic application, so can't foresee when the situation happens.

I present and example below

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)
my_data <- 
data_frame(
    cat = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 30, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1)),
    num1 = runif(30,1,6),
    num2 = runif(30,100,200),
    )  %>%
    mutate(num2 = ifelse(row_number() == 14, NA, num2))
```

1. The plot without symbol mapping (no 2 element category) displays correct color for NA

   ```
   plot_ly(
   data = my_data,
       type = "scatter",
       mode = "markers",
       x = ~cat,
       y = ~num1,
       color = ~num2,
       #symbol =~cat,          ## symbol mapping commented
   marker = list(size = 20),
   text = ~num2)
   ```

[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua7Ej.png)

2. The plot with symbols displays the same color for both points.

   ```
   plot_ly(
       data = my_data,
           type = "scatter",
           mode = "markers",
           x = ~cat,
           y = ~num1,
           color = ~num2,
           symbol =~cat,
       marker = list(size = 20),
       text = ~num2
   )
   ```

[plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8YVA.png)
Circled point should be NA color (gray)

Answer (score 0):

Just writing NA like this doesn't specify the `type` of NA. I don't know for sure but I suspect that is an NA "character" and not an NA "number." See below, pay attention to the NA introduction. Find a way to convert your NAs to NA_real_, I suggest dplyr if NA then NA_real_ else leave it alone type of statement.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)
my_data <- 
data_frame(
cat = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 30, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1)),
num1 = runif(30,1,6),
num2 = runif(30,100,200),
)  %>%
mutate(num2 = ifelse(row_number() == 14, NA_real_, num2))

plot_ly(
data = my_data,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers",
    x = ~cat,
    y = ~num1,
    color = ~num2,
    symbol =~cat,
marker = list(size = 20),
text = ~num2
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't changes the behaviour, the marker with the NA_real_ value still appears coloured. The only approach I've found is to plot two traces, one with the NA data and one with the !NA data.

Comment: It worked on my end, but now not working on my lap top (R 3.5.2 win10). Let me think about it for a second.